# How to create a 'muti-request-safe' postgresql function to generate distinct sequential numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, locking

I need to generate and store sequential unique numbers, per category, in a context with possible multiple requests at the same time.

My current database is Postgresql and my idea is to have a table to store those numbers and use a function to generate them.

The function (aka stored procedure) is responsible to generate the new number and ensure (via LOCK directive) it's uniqueness per category.

I thought about using the "LOCK" directive but I found a strange behavior: if I use "ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE" I receive more conflict than using "SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE": for me this is a non-sense because "ACCESS EXCLUSIVE" should lock the entire table for the entire time of the function in ALL possible way (at least this is my understanding from the official documentation..).

I tried this solution with Postgresql 10.4 and test it with a c# Xunit test that make a loop and for each iteration simulate '100' simultaneous connections and request to generate the unique number (call the function).

If I use "ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE", after some iteration (100/200 numbers correctly generated) I receive the exception given by a unique index.

If I use "SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE", after 58 iterations (580 numbers correctly generated) I receive the exception.

Why?

The script to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS protocol
(
  id             UUID         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  code           BIGINT                default 0 NOT NULL,
  registry__id   UUID         NOT NULL,
  registry__name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  what           varchar(255) NULL,

  createdat      timestamp    not null,
  createdby      varchar(255)
);


-- cannot use unique constraint because works only with columns
-- with an index i can add the unique constraint that I want
-- note: this constraint does not check if there are 2 equal code with different year!
create unique index protocol_per_year on "protocol" (
     code,
     registry__id,
     extract(year from createdat)
);
```

The Function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS createNewProtocol(uuid, varchar, varchar, uuid, timestamp);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createNewProtocol(in registryId uuid,
                                             in what varchar,
                                             in createdby varchar,
                                             in protocolId uuid,
                                             in createdAtValue timestamp) RETURNS bigint AS
$$
DECLARE
  registryName VARCHAR := null;
  startFromVal bigint  := null;
  codeVal      bigint  := null;
  lastCode     bigint  := null;
  resetByYear  boolean := false;
BEGIN

  LOCK TABLE "protocol" IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  --LOCK TABLE "protocol" IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

  SELECT p.name, p.startfrom, p.reseteveryyear INTO STRICT registryName, startFromVal, resetByYear
  from "protocolregistry" p
  where p.id = registryId;

  IF registryName IS NULL || registryName = '' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Can not find protocol registry with id %', registryId;
  end if;


  IF resetByYear THEN
    lastCode := (SELECT p.code
                 from "protocol" p
                 where p.registry__id = registryId
                   AND EXTRACT(year from p.createdat) = EXTRACT(year from createdAtValue)
                 ORDER BY p.createdat DESC
                 LIMIT 1);
  ELSE
    lastCode := (SELECT p.code from "protocol" p where p.registry__id = registryId ORDER BY p.createdat DESC LIMIT 1);
  END IF;


  codeVal = 0;

  if lastCode IS NULL then
    codeVal = startFromVal;
  ELSE
    codeVal = lastCode + 1;
  end if;

  INSERT INTO "protocol" (id, code, registry__id, registry__name, what, createdat, createdby)
  VALUES (protocolId, codeVal, registryId, registryName, what, createdAtValue, createdby);


  RETURN codeVal;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. First, you supply the prospective primary key for `protocol` in the `protocolId` parameter of `createNewProtocol`, so no matter how crazy you lock the table, there will be a primary key violation if you call the function twice with the same UUID for `protocolId`. What is the reason for all this? Why don't you use a sequence?

Comment: You are right, I explain: I generate earlier the protocol.Id (UUID) in the back-end.
In this way I don't need to return the code AND the ID.
The reason to do not use a sequence is because I want to manage more than one 'serie' and for each one I want to 'customize' the serie with 'start from' or 'reset the code every year'.
Example: I want a registry for the Invoices; this registry must be resetted to 0 every year. I also want a registry for documents: this should be universal ...and so one..

Comment: So where is the problem? Don't call your function with the same UUID twice, then no primary key conflict can occur. You normally don't need explicit table locks, and they block autovacuum, which is bad.

Comment: There is no problem with the .Id field because i don't pass the same UUID. 
The problem is with the function that generate the same code when multiple calls are made simultaneously: this happen in a random way: this SHOULD not happen tnx to the LOCK directive.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot comprehend your function. There is no explanation of the tables and the meaning of its columns.